# Which type of charger for soda syphon batter

Tags: batter, soda

I'm looking for a recipe for batter using a soda siphon. Since the term  *soda siphon*, as opposed to the cream whipper is used, I assumed the cartridges should be CO<sub>2</sub>. (The recipe doesn't say that.) I've found a few online posts that say it's better to use NO<sub>2</sub> cartridges.

Do you have any advice?

Comment: Please don't use NO2, which is toxic, for any food. The gas you mean is N2O.

Answer (score 2):

Many batters made in a soda syphon/whipper that I have seen, and used myself, use CO<sub>2</sub>. This is common when the goal is aeration.  Though, I have also seen N<sub>2</sub>O used.

A description of what you are making, and which brand of whipper, might allow a better response.

Comment: My apologies I’ve re-read the recipe and Heston says to use CO2.  The recipe involves flour, rice flour, honey, vodka and lager, and a spell in the ‘fridge.   It’s an isi syphon, 0.5L. Apparently it has a safety valve.  Looking at  couple of other recipes for isi and doing the maths on quantities, it looks like halving Heston recipe and using the 0.5L syphon with two CO2 charges is the way to go.  I’ll report the results!!